# Why isn't the local variable destroyed here?

Tags: c++

I knew that when i am creating a variable inside a function, it gets destroyed immediately after the function call. Why are p[0] and p[1] still equal to 123 if the pointer x got destroyed after f's call?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int *p;

void f()
{
    int *x;

    x = new int[2];

    x[0] = x[1] = 123;

    p=x;

    /// delete x;  if i delete x p[0] and p[1] are some kind of random int s;
}
int main()
{   f();

    cout<<p[0]<<p[1];

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `new int[2];` is on the heap and not a local variable; and `p` is still pointing at it.  Some advice - don't use  `new` and `delete` instead use `std::vector<T>` for local buffers/arrays and `std::make_unique` for owning pointers. Only use raw pointers ( eg `int *x;`) as observer pointers.

Comment: The _pointer_ `x` got destroyed after `f` was called. The _stuff it pointed to_ did not, unless you called `delete[] x;`.

Comment: "I have a piece of paper named `x`. I asked the OS to build me a house, and it did, and told me the address of my house, and I wrote the address on my `x` paper. Then I destroyed the paper. Why does the house still exist?"

Comment: `if i delete x p[0] and p[1] are some kind of random int s` 1) It should be `delete [] x;` 2: The values are not random they illegal to accesses (i.e. UB). Reading them can generate random values but just as easily crash or you could find the values `123` there as well (in production code probably would be (the same value), as the production lib tend not to do anything if they don't need to and leaving them the same value is cheaper than overwriting them for debug purposes).

Answer (score 4):

> I knew that when i am creating a variable inside a function, it gets destroyed immediately after the function call.

Correct.

> Why are p[0] and p[1] still equal to 123 if the pointer x got destroyed after f's call?

Because the array of dynamic objects pointed by the destroyed pointer `x` is unaffected by the pointer being destroyed.

The dynamic array is not deleted at all and you have a memory leak.

> if i delete x p[0] and p[1] are some kind of random int s;

If you delete `x`, then `p` will be invalid and attempting to access through it results in undefined behaviour.

---

P.S. Avoid using bare owning pointers. Also avoid unnecessary dynamic allocations.

Answer (score 1):

"Destroyed" in this case means that the variable `x` *goes out of scope* when the function ends, but it does **not** mean that the memory it points to is freed. What's happening here is:

1. You assign `x = p`, so `x` and `p` both hold the same memory address and therefore point to the same memory allocation.
2. `x` goes out of scope, but `p` doesn't, and nothing happens to the memory pointed to by `p`.
3. You use `p` to access the memory, which is perfectly valid since `p` has not gone out of scope and the memory it points to has not been freed.

What's crucial to understand is that the variable `x` and the memory you allocated are two separate things with their own lifetimes, even though `x` points to the memory. `x` going out of scope doesn't free the memory, and likewise freeing the memory doesn't cause `x` to go out of scope.

Answer (score -1):

The way to "fix" your code without changing too much of it is to use [`std::shared_ptr<int[]>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).

```
#include <memory>
std::shared_ptr<int[]> p;

void f()
{
    auto x = std::make_shared<int[]>(2);

    x[0] = x[1] = 123;

    p=x;
}
```

On the other hand, if you **intend** for the heap-allocated memory to be released at the end of `f()`, then `std::unique_ptr` should be used:

```
void f()
{
    auto x = std::make_unique<int[]>(2);

    x[0] = x[1] = 123;
}
```

Or, if your intent is to transfer ownership to `p`:

```
std::unique_ptr<int[]> p;

void f()
{
    auto x = std::make_unique<int[]>(2);

    x[0] = x[1] = 123;

    p=std::move(x);
}
```

Better yet is to avoid all of this entirely with [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

```
#include <vector>
std::vector<int> p;

void f()
{
    auto x = std::vector<int>(2);

    x[0] = x[1] = 123;

    p=std::move(x);
}
```